# Some ideas to create a code to run functions one after another (DOM)

Tags: javascript

I have some functions to manipulate the DOM.
One create some css styles, other some html elements, then some css again an so on 
(for example 7-8 steps)

Every function depends more or less of the previous. A callback approach is needed.

I know how to create that buy I'd like some function like that (avoiding to write the callback calls by hand )

```
My_dom_auto.add (function () {} ); // 1
My_dom_auto.add (function () {} ); // 2
My_dom_auto.add (function () {} ); // 3
My_dom_auto.run ();
```

My_dom_auto.add will encapsulate the function received into a new one, something like this:

```
My_dom_auto.add = fucntion (original_function_code) {

 fake_function.push (
     original_funcion_code_coied_line_by_line ;
     My_dom.internal_function()
}
}
```

So I could call the fake_functions ...

The question is .... Could it be done ? How ? Using function Object ? 
Other .... how to inject a new last line inside a function ?

What do you think? Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (with a polyfill)

Comment: please reformulate the question

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be useful to use Stack (abstract data type)

use an array in order to push functions
 (cssStyle_1 -> HtmlElement_1 -> cssStyle_2 -> HtmlElement_2->...  )

then pop function and execute it one after the other

```
a= function(){console.log("1") }
b= function(){console.log("2") }
c= function(){console.log("3") }

tab = []

tab.push(a)
tab.push(b)
tab.push(c)

tab.pop()
// 3
tab.pop()
// 2
tab.pop()
// 1
```